# How to use a reserved word to name field on selection?

Tags: mysql

I have a field called `action_type`.

How can I run this *query* and use a *reserved word (Type)*

```
Select action_type as Action Type from mytable
```

Comment: When will people finally start reading the manuals of the tools they use?

Comment: MySQL uses backticks for this case. This doesn't comply with the SQL standard, so it is advisable to switch to ANSI_QUOTES mode in MySQL and use the standard double quotes `"` then. And anyway, I would just generally avoid reserved words for names. In your example, you could simply use an alias `action_type` and be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) (or special characters or spaces) you have to put it in backticks

```
select action_type as `type` from your_table
```